# How to rename list of files to a partial same name plus numbered sequence before extension

Tags: bash, batch-rename

```
mv MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_P1_1.csv ../MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_1.csv
mv MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_P2_1.csv ../MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_2.csv
mv MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_P2_2.csv ../MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_3.csv
mv MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_P2_3.csv ../MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_4.csv
mv MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_P2_4.csv ../MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_5.csv
mv MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_P3_1.csv ../MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_6.csv
mv MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_P3_2.csv ../MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_7.csv
mv MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_P3_3.csv ../MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_8.csv
mv MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_P3_4.csv ../MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_9.csv
mv MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_P3_5.csv ../MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_10.csv
mv MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_P3_6.csv ../MIPS_236_CONTROLLING_HIGH_BLOOD_PRESSURE_CA_20221701_Denominator_11.csv
```

Comment: What does the body of the question have to do with the title? Where is the commands you have tried so we can see what the error might be? No one will do this for you but someone might help you fix an error.

Comment: consider copying first to another directory then on that directory use krename, krusader, multi-rename with a ##{0} to get a 0-99 counter.